# Card.io not conforming with protocol CardIOPaymentViewControllerDelegate

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, viewcontroller, card.io

I started to set up the code to use Card.io and am already getting this error, any advice on how to get through this issue?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/v8qx4.png

Comment: Implement the functions that are  required by the `CEDiOPaymentViewControllerDelegate` protocol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting this error because you have not implemented all the `delegate` methods of `CardIOPaymentViewControllerDelegate`

Implement this required methods in your controller

```
userDidCancelPaymentViewController
```

And

```
userDidProvideCreditCardInfo
```

Comment: I would like to, but because I have a rep of less than 15 it is recorded but not publicly shown